# PHP-FPM: pm.process_idle_timeout for PM = static or dynamic

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php.ini

I'm working with CentOS 8 and PHP-FPM setting for PM = static or dynamic does not allow an option for pm.process_idle_timeout.

```
; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
```

What I'm confused about is when PM is set to static or dynamic how PHP-FPM decides on when to kill idle processes?

Also, I was wondering the difference between pm.process_idle_timeout vs php.ini setting of max_execution_time. In my past experience, when I set up pm.process_idle_timeout to 5 seconds and my PHP script took 10 seconds to receive a response from MySQL server, the browser would time out.

I greatly appreciate anyone who can clear the above confusion for me.